# Finding example

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $\Omega$ is a simple connected open set and $z_0 \in \Omega$. Let $f : \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ be a holomorphic function such that $f(z_0) = z_0$ and $|f'(z_0)| = 1$.

1. If $\Omega \neq \mathbb{C}$, show that $f$ is a bijection.
2. Give an example that shows that $f$ must not be a bijection if $\Omega = \mathbb{C}$.

I was able to show the first part, but I do not find a counterexample for the second part.
I was looking for a simplest example possible, so I tried first $f(z) = z$, but that function is bijective. Next, I tried $f(z) = z^2$, but there are no points that statisfies the conditions.
From this, I thought that no polynomial will do the job. Therefore I tried something in the form of $e^{iz}$, but this function does not have fixed points.

From this, I am out of ideas, someone who can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(z)=\sin(z)$ and $z_0=0$. Then $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=\cos(0)=1$. But the sine function is indedeed not injective.

Comment: Thanks! But how does this proposition then work if we take for example $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $f(z) = \sin(z)$ because $\mathbb{R}$ is simply connected.

Comment: That $\Omega$ is not an open subset of $\Bbb C$